# Creating sub-packages in android studio problem

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, directory, package

I am having a really bothering issue. In my app, I am trying to reorganize my classes under com.proje.myapp folder. Under this folder I have a package named screenparts. And I am creating a new folder called dialog_fragments.When i tried to move a class from screenparts folder to dialog_fragments folder, move(refactor) screen pops up. So far everything normal. But when i pressed the refactor button it does some process in the background but folder does not move. And refactor button disables (i can't push it twice). Can anybody help me about that issue? What is the right way to reorganize under subfolders after the app is already done?

Answer (score 1):

Go to c drive and android studio project and search com/proje/myapp folder then copy or cut  files . Then go to dialogue_fragment paste inside this folder

Comment: Thanks for solution. It worked well. But for better understanding, How can i do this on android-studio? And do you have any idea i am having such problem?